# Unable to Get Extract elements using Xslt

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, soap

I am trying to write an `xslt` to modify an `xml`. This is a response that is received by a synchronous call. This xml's structure needs to be modified and the data needs to be transferred so that the response can be consumed by the originating system.

The input XML is as below:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns0:ValidateMeterItemResponse xmlns:ns0="http://www.apsc.com/CCB/ValidateMeterItem/InOut">
         <ns1:ValidateMeterItemRes xmlns:ns1="http://www.apsc.com/CCB/MeterServices/InOut">
            <ns1:verificationStatus>M2IV</ns1:verificationStatus>
            <ns1:errorCode>256.0</ns1:errorCode>
            <ns1:errorText>Service Point ID 1245765566 field invalid</ns1:errorText>
            <ns1:readingDetails/>
         </ns1:ValidateMeterItemRes>
      </ns0:ValidateMeterItemResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The Expected Output XML is:

```
<responseMessage/">
    <response>
        <errorCode>256.0</errorCode>
    </response>
</responseMessage>
```

I am trying to just extract only one node for now.

Below is the XSLT that I have written. I first copied all the elements as-is, and then tried to do away with the `<ValidateMeterItemResponse>` node. Then I try to build my xml (with a different structure) by selecting certain elements from the input xml using `xsl value of`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/OUMWM/Message"
xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/OUMWM/Message1">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:template>
       <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <responseMessage>
            <response>
                <errorCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns1:ValidateMeterItemRes/ns1:errorCode" />
                </errorCode>
            </response>
        </responseMessage>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am unable to extract the element even after all the paths are right. I am sure I have missed something trying accomplish this. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you have is that your namespace URIs differ between XML and XSLT. In the XML you have these defined..

```
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"       
xmlns:ns0="http://www.apsc.com/CCB/ValidateMeterItem/InOut"
xmlns:ns1="http://www.apsc.com/CCB/MeterServices/InOut"
```

But in the XSLT you have these...

```
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/OUMWM/Message"
xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/OUMWM/Message1"
```

It is the namespace URIs that must match, not the prefix.

The other issue is that in your xpath expression in the final template, you have missed out `ns0:ValidateMeterItemResponse`. The xpath expression also starts with `SOAP-ENV:Envelope` which is not needed because your template already matches the root element, and so the xpath expression is relative to that.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:ns0="http://www.apsc.com/CCB/ValidateMeterItem/InOut"
xmlns:ns1="http://www.apsc.com/CCB/MeterServices/InOut">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <responseMessage>
            <response>
                <errorCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="SOAP-ENV:Body/ns0:ValidateMeterItemResponse/ns1:ValidateMeterItemRes/ns1:errorCode" />
                </errorCode>
            </response>
        </responseMessage>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you very much.!! Appreciate your help!! it worked!